# How should I design a view model with many models?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

If you have a view model with a number of models (i.e. ten plus), each requiring the same functionality (i.e. binding properties) - and the only thing being different is the actual model type. Does it make sense for each of them to have its own binding property or should I re-factor this design into something more elegant like a dictionary of models, requiring only one binding property and the key being a string associated with the model. Or is there a better alternative to a dictionary?

I am trying to simplify the design of my view models in general, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add a code sample. Also, consider asking this question on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What exactly is a “binding property”? You can *data bind* to properties, that does not really make those properties special though. Do you mean dependency properties? You don’t need to have dependency properties to make them bindable. For normal models, you should consider implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: How about defining a common class or interface for your models and then keeping a `List<>` of them all?

Comment: @poke - no sorry, poor choice of wording on my part, I just mean the properties which expose the model to the view for data binding. Will edit now :) and, I do use INotifyPropertyChanged. I am just talking about how to reduce the number of properties required to expose models to the view.

Comment: your question is too broad, answer to which will depend on the number of factors like how you want your models to be rendered, are they extend the same base type, what is actual business requirement. you will need to share the good code sample to clarify these.

Comment: @Shoe - yeahh, so similar to the idea of having a dictionary, do you think that is a fair solution though? Or am I over engineering the MVVM design patter if I do this?

Comment: @nit - they do all share a common base type, to give further insight into my scenario I am building an information system, a few of the views are large (in terms of the data they hold) but are tabulated into sections, each section having its own model (to support lazy loading and basically to avoid having one huge model to be passed around). I can post a code sample, however I am only talking about basic properties, what I am asking is more relative to structure than the codes itself. So, I'm not exactly sure what code sample would be of use - please advise, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing

I had different Classes such as `CustomerData`, `EmployeeData`, `OrderData`
i collected all these classes in 1 collection called Collection (obviously)
and i set the collection to the views dataContext from there on i just used the right path to reference the data i needed in my xaml for example `Text="{Binding Path=CustomerData.Name}"` or `Text="{Binding Path=EmployeeData.Name"}"`

**EDIT** to answer comment:
i have one class called Data which conatians my OnPropertyChanged.
when ever i need to do something if the data is changed i simply say this in the class where i created the data or in the class that uses it.

```
collection.CustomerData.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Customer_PropertyChanged);
```

also an example of one of my classes:
    public class CustomerData : Data
    {
        private string company = "";
        private string ship = "";
        private string adress = "";
        private string city = "";
        private string zipCode = "";
        private string country = "";
        private string btw_nmbr = "";
        private bool isTempCustomer = true;
        private List phoneNumbers;
        private List eMailAdresses;

```
    private string fileName;

    #region public methods
    public string Company
    {
        get
        {
            return company;
        }
        set
        {
            if (company.Trim() != value.Trim())
            {
                company = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Company");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Ship
    {
        get
        {
            return ship;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ship.Trim() != value.Trim())
            {
                ship = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Ship");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Adress
    {
        get
        {
            return adress;
        }
        set
        {
            if (adress.Trim() != value.Trim())
            {
                adress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Adress");
            }
        }
    }

    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return city;
        }
        set
        {
            if (city.Trim() != value.Trim())
            {
                city = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("City");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ZipCode
    {
        get
        {
            return zipCode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (zipCode.Trim() != value.Trim())
            {
                zipCode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ZipCode");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Country
    {
        get
        {
            return country;
        }
        set
        {
            if (country.Trim() != value.Trim())
            {
                country = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Country");
            }
        }
    }

    public string BTW_Nmbr
    {
        get
        {
            return btw_nmbr;
        }
        set
        {
            if (btw_nmbr.Trim() != value.Trim())
            {
                btw_nmbr = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BTW_Nmbr");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsTempCustomer
    {
        get
        {
            return isTempCustomer;
        }
        set
        {
            isTempCustomer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsTempCustomer");
        }
    }

    public List<ContactData> PhoneNumbers
    {
        get
        {
            return phoneNumbers;
        }
        set
        {
            phoneNumbers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PhoneNumbers");
        }
    }

    public void AddPhoneNumber(ContactData cd)
    {
        phoneNumbers.Add(cd);
        OnPropertyChanged("PhoneNumbers");
    }

    public List<ContactData> EmailAdresses
    {
        get
        {
            return eMailAdresses;
        }
        set
        {
            eMailAdresses = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EmailAdresses");
        }
    }

    public void AddEmailAdress(ContactData cd)
    {
        eMailAdresses.Add(cd);
        OnPropertyChanged("EmailAdresses");
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return fileName;
        }
        set
        {
            fileName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, one thing though, how did you then manage model changes (i.e. INotifyPropertyChanged), did you call the change on the entire collection? as surely this would be quite costly?

Comment: does my edit answer your question?
p.s.
you could also use the abstarct class Data to creat a list<Data> data but than you will have to check to get the right data object like so: foreach(Data d in data){if(d is Customer)}